# Deleting s3 object

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I am storing user profile images on s3. When user changes his profile image, I generate a new s3 key and store newly returned url as user profile image.
I delete the old key. However, I can still access the previous image via old URL though key has been deleted. Following is my relevant code snippet

```
import boto
conn = boto.connect_s3( AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY )
image_bucket = conn.get_bucket( IMAGE_BUCKET )
old_s3_key = user.get_old_key()
image_bucket.delete_key( old_s3_key )
```

Does s3 takes time to remove the url associated with the key?

Answer (score 0):

It might take a short amount of time before consistency is achieved but I don't think that would explain this behavior.  I don't know what your `get_old_key()` method is returning but the `delete_key()` method expects the name of a key.  Is that what you are passing in?

The S3 service does not return an error if you try to delete a key that does not exist in the bucket so if you are passing in the wrong value to `delete_key()` it would fail silently.

Comment: get_old_key() is a custom method that I wrote which returns the key that needs to be deleted.

Comment: Does it return the Key object or the name of the key as a string?